# Print outputting objects to a .txt file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I have this code:

```
ArrayList<Employee> ArrEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>(); //  array for employee objects

        try {
            Scanner txtIn = new Scanner(new File("/Users/PatrickBui/Documents/workspace/COMP 249 - Assignment 3/src/payroll.txt"));

        for (int i = 0; i < ArrEmployee.size(); ++i){   
            while (txtIn.hasNext()) { // looping through the payroll.txt file and creating Employee objects from its data
                try{
                long EmployeeNumber = txtIn.nextLong();
                String EmployeeName = txtIn.next();
                String LastName = txtIn.next();
                double HoursWorked = txtIn.nextDouble();
                double HourlyWage = txtIn.nextDouble();
                    if (ArrEmployee.get(i).getHourlyWage() > 10.35){ 
                    throw new InputMismatchException(); // throws exception if the hourly wage is less than 10.35$
                }
                    ArrEmployee.add(new Employee(EmployeeNumber,EmployeeName,LastName,HoursWorked,HourlyWage));

                }
                catch (InputMismatchException n) { // catching long,strings and doubles in the payroll.txt that aren't valid
                    PrintWriter txtOut = new PrintWriter("/Users/PatrickBui/Documents/workspace/COMP 249 - Assignment 3/src/payrollError.txt");
                    txtOut.println(Employee.EmployeeNumber + " " + Employee.EmployeeName + " " + Employee.LastName + " " + Employee.HoursWorked + " " + Employee.HourlyWage);
                    txtOut.close();
                      }
            }
        }
```

And I'm trying to figure out a way as you can see, for my `catch (InputMismatchException n)` to write the variables EmployeeNumber, [...], HourlyWage into a file called payrollError.txt

I've tried so many times but nothing happens to the payrollError.txt file... There must be something wrong with my code but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Are you using MAC OS?

Comment: Are you ever *throwing* the exception? And shouldn't you be appending to that error file?

Comment: @GRC I am using OS X.

Comment: @EJP Yes, and what does appending mean? Im still a java newbie

Comment: @X1XX PrintWriter constructor throws file does not exception. Appending means you are writing to the end of file.

Comment: @X1XX I do not know but your problem might be space in your path.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment, but the reputation does not let me...

The following code works for me:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    File f = new File("test.txt");
    f.createNewFile();
    PrintWriter txt = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
        txt.println("testing, testing, 1 2 3");
         txt.close();
    }
}
```